# Is it possible in Xamarin.Forms to make non square labels?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to achieve something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZdw1.jpg

Is it possible in Xamarin.Forms to have label that expands his width when there is no more of image left?
 I was looking for answer for some time now, didnt find anything that fits.

Comment: I am not sure if you can achieve what you want with a Xamarin.Forms.View (Grid, StackLayout, Absolute Layout) but you can achieve something like this:
https://s13.postimg.org/7cvjd0ijb/Screen_Shot_2016_11_14_at_9_25_31_AM.png

Comment: I tried it but the problem is that I dont know how much text will it fit in first label, text comes from database so its imposible to do it manually as well, because it just depends on the case. For every model I have diffrent text for the big label and fitting icon that should be placed in corner. Can two labels share one text ?

Comment: Unless from the server side they separate the text that will another option.